# CS50 Substitution, problem with checking for duplicates and checking all characters are alphabetic

Tags: c, cs50

This code is not finished, but I'm having two problems.
First, when the key has non-alphabetic characters in it, the error message "Key must only contain letters" is printed as many times as there are non alphabetic characters ex: if there is four numbers in the key, the error message will print four times.
Second, the error message is not printed when the key contains repeated letters, instead the program acts as though the key is valid.

Thank you for any advice.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesarsub key\n");
    return 1;
}
// Check key contains only letters
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1] [i]))
        {
            printf("Key must only contain letters\n");
        }
        // Check letters are not repeated
        else
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int m = i + 1; n < strlen(argv[1]); m++)
            {
                if (argv[1][i] == argv[1][m])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0)
            printf("Key must not contain repeated characters\n");
            }
        }
// Check key contains 26 letters
if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must be 26 letters\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the difference between the routine that checks for the existence of the argument (ie `if (argc != 2)`) and the routine that checks for alpha only (ie `if (!isalpha(argv[1] [i]))`). One exits the program (which is to see "returns from the main function") and one does not.

The other problem looks like a typo here `for (int m = i + 1; n < strlen(argv[1]); m++)`. The for loop doesn't execute because `n < strlen...` is never true.